# Password prompt in pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords, stdin, tty

I am trying to prompt the user for his password in pycharm, without echoing back the password in the console output.

I have tried to use the getpass module, but it will echo it back. How could I do this, or make getpass not echo the password in pycharm?

Here's a bit of digging into the code:

`getpass` first tries to manipulate the tty, but it throws an exception

```
>>> os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY)
OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured: '/dev/tty'
```

It then tries to manipulate the stdin, but it also throws an exception:

```
>>> sys.stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: StdIn instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Does anyone know of a way to make either work?

Comment: I dont think it is possible, why do you want it with pycharm?

Comment: Well, because it's the IDE I use, and I launch my scripts from there